# Trying to obtain specific data from an API with different ID's but nothing logs to the console

Tags: reactjs, api, async-await, get, axios

I'm trying to access data from an API that has 10 different ID's (1 - 10) with each ID containing bits of mock information for a client. The base URL is

https://europe-west2-mpx-tools-internal.cloudfunctions.net/frontend-mock-api/clients

Adding the {clientId} to the end of the URL return the last 30 days of data for a specific client for instance: https://europe-west2-mpx-tools-internal.cloudfunctions.net/frontend-mock-api/clients/1 returns data like so:

[image]

But when I try to console.log data containing the (date, cost, impressions, clicks, conversions), nothing appears, I'm not getting an error

Here's my code from both files:

[image]

[image]

I'm essentially wondering how best to ensure I'm able to access the specific bits of data for each day and for each client from 1 - 10.

I'm not getting an error but believe I'm going wrong somewhere if anyone can help.

Thanks in advance and sorry if I've missed key info that's needed as I'm still learning!

Comment: have you seen your network tab what is the response in that?

Comment: Hi, I'm actually building this in codesandbox so don't actually have a Network tab to look at I don't believe, just a console, problem and react dev-tools bar but no errors in any

Comment: you can check network tab in codesandbox also you will find your API call

Comment: it shows as making 10 requests in the network tab, but the console.log(data) shows everything as undefined